# A batch script to zip only certain types of files

Tags: batch-file

So far I have this, it basically just zips everything within the folder the .bat script is placed at:

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "aa.zip"
```

What I wish to do is only zip the folders within that directory, not the script itself or any other files that might exist.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do ("c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "aa.zip" %%a)
```

That should do what you want. For more info type:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.chm"
```

And goto "Command Line Version" -> "Commands"

I'm pretty sure there is a builtin method to add all folders in a direcotry to an archive.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

suppose you wish to not include excel(.xls) files and .bat file you can try this:

> for /r /D %%A in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%A.zip" -xr!*.bat "%%A" -r -x!*.xls

just replace the format you'd wish to add in the place of xls or you can add addition file type

> -r -x!*.xls -x!*.pdf